# Pragma Solidity Error Unused Local Variable uint256 testVar = 5; | What's wrong?

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, remix

I would like to know what's wrong with the code below. I can validate the transactions, but I keep receiving the error "Unused Local Variable "

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract SimpleStorage {
    //boolean (True False),uint(>0), int(><=0), address, bytes
    bool HasFavoriteNumber = true;
    uint256 public FavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _FavoriteNumber) public {
        FavoriteNumber = _FavoriteNumber;
        uint256 testVar = 5;
    }
    
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256){
        return FavoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPiTd.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning you can just ignore it. It is giving you this warning because it is a local variable, i.e the scope of this variable is only inside this function, every time you are calling this function, it is assigning 5 to the variable but it is not stored anywhere. But it you for suppose to make it global and then assign the value to it it will run fine. However, assigning 5 every time to it will be useless so just for the sake of it I am incrementing 5 every time the function is called.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract SimpleStorage {
    //boolean (True False),uint(>0), int(><=0), address, bytes
    bool HasFavoriteNumber = true;
    uint256 public FavoriteNumber;
    uint256 public testVar;

    function store(uint256 _FavoriteNumber) public {
        FavoriteNumber = _FavoriteNumber;
        testVar += 5;
    }
    
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256){
        return FavoriteNumber;
    }
```

Comment: So, when I add a "+" in the equation in the first part of it, I add the value of the 2nd part every time it's called? It would increase the gas? 

Thank you for the response.

Comment: basically, it is a short hand for `testVar = testVar + 5`. In regards of gas it doesn't really make a really big difference.